# How to redirect all the content of one file to another file?

Tags: io-redirection

I have two files: file_a and file_b. I want to redirect (`>`) all content of file_a into file_b.

pseudo code is `file_a > file_b`. how to do that? I feel I should use cat.

Comment: `cat file_a > file_b`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest pleaes make that an answer. Trivial though it is.

Comment: @roaima, I can't: it's too primitive and not imposing ...

Comment: @roaima It's only "trivial" if you disregard what's going on ;-)  (what's opening what file and what's happening to permissions etc. in various cases)

Comment: @Kusalananda at the level the OP is asking the simple form of the answer is trivial ("How do you get a directory listing? - `ls`"), although I accept that if you have zero knowledge nothing is really trivial. I like your answer because it gives a solution at the simplest possible level, but then goes on to explain for other readers some of the extras that might be relelvant.

Comment: Coming here from googling, I found this question useful. It should be upvoted for people like me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nitpick: In Unix, you can redirect output or input streams, but you can't redirect *files*.

As RomanPerekhrest suggested in comments to the question:

```
cat file_a >file_b
```

This redirects the standard output stream (or just "the output") of `cat` into `file_b`.  The output of `cat` will be the contents of `file_a`.

This has the same effect (disregarding edge-case differences regarding permissions and ownership) as

```
cp file_a file_b
```

There are many other ways of duplicating a file's complete contents into another file, including trivial examples that apply non-modifying filters on text files, such as

```
dd if=file_a of=file_b

awk '1' file_a >file_b

sed '' file_a >file_b
```

etc.

All the above examples will *overwrite* the previous contents of `file_b`.

To *append* to `file_b`, replace `>` in the examples above that uses `>` with `>>`, e.g.

```
cat file_a >>file_b
```

To append the contents of `file_a` to that of `file_b` and store that in a third file:

```
cat file_b file_a >file_c
```

`cat` will output the contents of each of its file arguments after each other, in order, and the result will be redirected into the new `file_c` file.

Comment: Depending on the implementation, the `sed`/`awk` ones may not work for non-text files. The `awk` one would add back a missing trailing newline character (`sed` as well with some implementations, some others would remove the unterminated line)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes. I've changed my wording to be slightly more careful.

Comment: I think what would make your nitpick even better is to say that you can redirect *standard streams*, or perhaps file descriptors in general. "Output of a program" can be arguably stretched as a term.

Answer (score 0):

simple way is to copy:

```
cp file1 file2
```

there are multiple ways to divert the flow of output data into another file as well e.g.:

```
cat file1 > file2
less file1 > file2
more file1 > file2
```

You can use rsync to take backup:

```
rsync -r /media/hdd1/Folder1/ /media/hdd2/Folder2/
```

rsync is backing up whole folder from one drive to another and -r option specifies to do it recursively for all files and subfolders.